# How to access a dependency of a dependency in Java/Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

I'm trying to access a library that is implemented in a library that I implement. I own both these libraries. I.e.:

**Lib1** has a certain class I want to access in the consumer app, say `Car.java`:

```
public class Car {
    public Int wheelsCount;
}
```

**Lib2** has an api which returns the class `Car` from lib1:

gradle.build:

```
...
api 'com.me.lib1:1.0' //From maven central (not currently live)
```

```
import com.lib1.Car

interface MyApi {
    public Car getCar();
}
```

**Consumer's** gradle.build: `implementation 'com.me.lib2:1.0'`

```
MyApi api = getMyApi()
api.getCar() // Error
```

> Cannot access class 'com.lib1.Car'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

**Question:** Is there a way to do this using gradle?

Comment: Do you mean `lib2` in consumer's `gradle.build`?

Comment: Anyway, marking lib1 dependency in lib2 as `api` should be enough to use its types. Please double-check it is `api` and not `implementation`, and if it is try to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you’re asking. Here is an example which I think should roughly do what you were talking about?

---

We have a gradle project with 3 subprojects, `car`, `garage` and `app`. `car` and `garage` provide libraries, whereas `app` is our application. Aside from these directories, the root directory contains only a `settings.gradle` with this content:

```
rootProject.name = 'example'
include 'car', 'garage', 'app'
```

---

Moving on, we have the `car` project which provides an interface. It’s `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
plugins {
  id 'java-library'
}
```

Other than that, it only contains our interface at `src/main/java/car/Car.java`:

```
package car;

public interface Car {
  void drive();
}
```

---

`garage` is a consumer for the `car` project, and provides a way to get new `Car`s. So we need to declare an `api` dependency on `:car` like this:

```
plugins {
  id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
  api project(':car')
}
```

The `Garage` class itself looks like this (under `src/main/java/garage/Garage.java`:

```
package garage;

import car.Car;

public class Garage {
  public Car getCar() {
    return () -> { System.out.println("Hello World!"); };
  }
}
```

---

Finally, we have our application which just needs an `implementation` dependency on `garage` to use it and a `JavaExec` task to run it:

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
}

dependencies {
  implementation project(':garage')
}

task run(type: JavaExec) {
  main = 'app.Main'
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

The actual implementation again goes to `src/main/java/app/Main.java`:

```
package app;

import garage.Garage;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Garage g = new Garage();
    g.getCar().drive();
  }
}
```

---

Now we can run the whole thing with `gradle :app:run`, which should give us output along these lines:

```
> Task :app:run
Hello World!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 506ms
6 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 5 up-to-date
<-------------> 0% WAITING
> IDLE
```

So as you can see, there’s nothing special you need to do beyond the things you’ve already stated. This is assuming you’re using classpaths. If you’re using the Java 9+ module system there are some additional steps, but this would be beyond the scope of this question I think.

Comment: My example would work if all the libraries were in the same gradle project, it doesn't when they're imported as jars, what does the line `classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath` do?

Comment: @JohnSardinha These things aren't all in the same gradle project. They're distributed across 3 projects, like I spell out in the answer. Whether or not it's in a Jar doesn't make any difference. The `classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath` like sets the `classpath` property of the `JavaExec` task to include everything from the `main` sourceSet and its dependencies. It doesn't affect compilation, that's just there for running the application.